# Save every scope from a Form in a service Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, forms

I would like to save my datas from my form to my service function setData(), but I am not sure how to do it. I have already done the service, the setData() function, and my form.

***Form***

```
<form id="eventForm" data-toggle="validator" class="text-left" role="form" name="form.eventForm">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <input type="text" ng-model="form.return" name="RT" id="return"> Return
          <input type="text" ng-model="form.oneway" name="OW" id="oneway"> One way
    </div>
    <button name="submit" class="btn btn-default ng-click="form.$valid && submit()">Pay now</button>
</form>
```

***AngularJS submit method***

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    FormData.setData($scope.form);
    $location.path("/flights");
}
```

***Service setData()***

```
this.data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("flights") || '{}');

this.setData = function(data) {
    this.data = data;
    sessionStorage.setItem("flights", JSON.stringify(data));
}
this.getData = function() {
    return this.data;
}
```

**I don't know how should I pass my whole data from my Form to setData() function.**

Comment: set your ng-model as **form.return** and **form.to**  and get **form** object in your controler

Comment: get form object by **$scope.form** not by **form** in your controller

Comment: @AravinthanK still nothing happen. Is there anything else I had to update ?

Comment: Refer this fiddler (https://jsfiddle.net/aravinthan93/22gua60a/2/)

Comment: change your code to this `ng-click=" form.eventForm.$valid && submit() "`

Comment: Thanks, it works!!! Its a pitty I can't put your answer as the one who help me, its a comment

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the submit button to disable on an invalid form, and set the submit action to send the form object. Then, in the controller, set the function to accept an argument (the form data), and use that.

**HTML**

```
<form id="eventForm" data-toggle="validator" class="text-left" role="form" name="form.eventForm">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <input type="text" ng-model="form.return" name="RT" id="return"> Return
          <input type="text" ng-model="form.oneway" name="OW" id="oneway"> One way
    </div>
    <button name="submit"
        class="btn btn-default
        ng-disabled="form.$invalid"
        ng-click="submit(form)">
        Pay no
    </button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.submit = function(submitData) {
    FormData.setData(submitData);
    $location.path("/flights");
}
```